# is it posible to compare image at realtime using camera with stored images in db, android java

Tags: java, android, database, image-processing, camera

I am doing image processing, but stuck in. can we implement realtime image processing, like the camera captures videos and also compares the object with stored images in data base, need algorithm for implementing this idea, any tutorial, link or source will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend using [OpenCv](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) for android. It allows a simple and very well working live processing. This library also comes with a wide variety of imageprocessing implementations. It is easy to convert the image-Object (Mat) to Bitmaps and so Files! OpenCv allows LowLevelImageProcessing which could be usefull to you to compere these images. It maybe seems a bit difficult to add this library to your project at first but, it is worth it!